# How to configure mysql in doctrine to connect via a proxy address?

Tags: mysql, symfony, heroku, doctrine-orm, proximo

I am running a Symfony 3 application on Heroku, using doctrine as the ORM. I need to connect to an external MySQL database that is behind a firewall. I obtained a static IP via [Proximo](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/proximo) and it is now white listed. If I connect to it via telnet it works:

`bin/proximo telnet IP 3306
Proxying traffic bound for 0.0.0.0/0 via Proximo host IP2
Trying IP...
Connected to IP.
Escape character is '^]'.`

However connecting the application is not working for me:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out
```

My Procfile looks like this:

```
web: bin/proximo bin/console cache:clear &&  bin/proximo $(composer config bin-dir)/heroku-php-nginx -C nginx_app.conf web/
```

How can I connect Doctrine using the Proximo proxy?